# Temporary folders in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

what is the difference between the user temporary folder and the windows temporary folder on my PC?

Answer (score 2):

One is for applications running under your user account, the other is for applications that are running under the system user account.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are only a security issues, the guest may not have access to the system temporary folder or to the other users' temporary folder.